# Using NSMutableArray in a Random Generator

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

I'm trying to pass the contents of a file into an array that will then be called by a random image generator. I am missing something (or a lot of things). Any ideas?

```
NSString *chords = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ChordCharts" ofType:nil];

chordCharts = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:chords];

int randomimages = rand() % 4;

switch (randomimages) {

    case 0:

        chordImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[chordCharts objectAtIndex:0]];

        break;

    case 1:

        chordImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[chordCharts objectAtIndex:1]];

        break;

    case 2:

        chordImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[chordCharts objectAtIndex:2]];

        break;

    case 3:

        chordImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[chordCharts objectAtIndex:3]];

        break;

    default:

        break;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, what's the problem? If you expect that the file can look like this

```
Name1.gif
Name2.jpg
...
```

then it won't work; "initWithContentsOf" on an array expects a plist file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plist version="1.0"><array>
   <string>Name1.gif</string>
   <string>Name2.jpg</string>
   ...
</array></plist>
```

If you want the first version of the file, you cold just read the file into a string, and use componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n" to split it into lines:

```
NSString* MyString=[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"..."];
NSArray* chordCharts=[MyString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
```

You might want to check for empty lines, and possibly trim the lines as well (to remove whitespace at the beginning and end)

Comment: Ah, didn't catch the plist thing. I will re-work the code. The real problem is that no images are showing up when this method is called. I was hoping to find an efficient way to store a large amount of .png files in an array and then call those addresses in the switch case. That way, I wouldn't have to write out so many UIImage names. Does that make sense?